# How to sort complex javascript array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays named `generationArray`. Each of the arrays inside of generation array is an array of 252 positions. The first 250 positions are internal code stuff and the two last positions represent my sorting criteria.
The last position of the array is a `boolean`, the one before is a number.

I need to order this `generationArray` first by all `true` or `false` values of its arrays and then for the numeric value. If the last position is true order by the bigger numbers first, if the last position is false order by the smaller numbers first.

This is an example, suppose `generationArray` has 5 arrays.

```
generationArray[0][last] == false
generationArray[0][last-1] == 350

generationArray[1][last] == true
generationArray[1][last-1] == 300

generationArray[2][last] == true
generationArray[2][last-1] == 250

generationArray[3][last] == false
generationArray[3][last-1] == 380

generationArray[4][last] == true
generationArray[4][last-1] == 290
```

It would have to be ordered like

```
generationArray[0][last] == true
generationArray[0][last-1] == 300

generationArray[1][last] == true
generationArray[1][last-1] == 290

generationArray[2][last] == true
generationArray[2][last-1] == 250

generationArray[3][last] == false
generationArray[3][last-1] == 350

generationArray[4][last] == false
generationArray[4][last-1] == 380
```

How do I achieve to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Is it a positive number always?

Comment: Yes, it's a game timer which is decreasing, so the lowest possible value is zero.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
generationArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[251]-a[251] || (a[251]*2-1)*(b[250]-a[250]);
})
```

- `b[251]-a[251]` casts the booleans to ints and compares them, `true`s before `falses`
- If that results in `0`, the `||` will be evaluated
- `b[250]-a[250]` [compares the ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/sort-not-working-with-integers), larger values first again
- but if the boolean was `false`, then `(a[251]*2-1)*` inverts that order.

---

Since your numbers are always positive, a maybe more common / easier understandable solution is to treat numbers whose boolean companion is `true` as negative. You even might simply restructure your data to use that pattern. Then all you have to do is a numerical sort:

```
generationArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a[251]?-a[250]:+a[250]) - (b[251]?-b[250]:+b[250]);
})
```